# Name of CSS style

Tags: css

This is a pretty small question, I've tried googling but without knowing the name of the style I'm getting nowhere fast. What is the design pattern called where the (i'm going to say blog cause that's where I've seen it used) blog text is a continuous scroll but the rest of page (ie headers and footers) is static?

As an  [example blog](https://blog.alexmaccaw.com/css-transitions)

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, elements are positioned static, relative to each other (`position: static;`). To position an element relative to the viewport, you use:

```
element {
    position: fixed;
}
```

This takes the element out of the normal text flow. See http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp for more information about positioning.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for

```
position:fixed
```

Now you got a fish, learn how to catch it :
You need to use your browser toolkit, or firebug for firefox, to select the element you want to inspect, then looking for it's source code and css rules, you will see by your own how it's made.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a specific styling terminology for it but all you need to do is add `position: fixed` to your header and/or footer.

```
#header {
   position: fixed;
}

#footer {
   position: fixed;
}
```